# endpoint and controller based authorization

Tags: .net, policy, authorize

.net core
endpoint and controller based authorization
Hi;
I have a project and I have both Admins and Members in this project. I call my admin users admin and my member users user. When creating a controller, I have a baseController and I can automatically create crud operations with a few lines of code. If there is a route starting with api/cms in this controller, the role of this endpoint should be admin, and if there is a route starting with api/platform, this endpoint role should be user. How can I provide both controller-based and endpoint-based authorization?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgR5.png)

AdvertController;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7uhH.png)

In the controller above GetAdvertsByLanguageCodeList
I want the user role to access the method, but I think my controller-based admin privilege is disrupting this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.